# how to run apply_gradients for more than one trainable_weights in TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2.x

I've build a encoder-decoder like deep learning model with TensorFlow2.0, and for certain reason the encoder and decoder are two seprate models, and I would like to optimize the two models with the optimizer.apply_gradients() function. The [TensorFlow document](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer) did not provide too much infomation for this case. It shows that the ***grads_and_vars*** should be *"List of (gradient, variable) pairs"*. I tried two method as shown below:

1st method:
`optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self._encoder.trainable_weights, self._decoder.trainable_weights))`

2nd method:
`optimizer.apply_gradients([zip(grads, self._encoder.trainable_weights), zip(grads, self._decoder.trainable_weights)])`

and neither works. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: What is the error? How were `grads` produced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a training loop like the following code, referenced from [DCGAN tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan).

```
with tf.GradientTape() as enc_tape, tf.GradientTape() as dec_tape:
    feature_space = encoder(images, training=True)
    recovered_image = decoder(feature_space, training=True)

    #Some custom loss function...
    loss = tf.keras.losses.MSE(recovered_image, images)

    gradients_of_encoder = enc_tape.gradient(loss , encoder.trainable_variables)
    gradients_of_decoder = dec_tape.gradient(loss, decoder.trainable_variables)

enc_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_encoder , encoder.trainable_variables))
dec_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_decoder , decoder.trainable_variables))
```